# a static variable to limit the number of processes

Tags: c#

I have multiple instances of a class that has a function that does some process that lasts more than an hour, and I need to allow only a max of 2 processes running at a time across all instances, and if the number of processes was 2 then it has to wait until the the value of running process goes under 2, so I came up with this

```
    public class SomeClass
    {
       private static int _ProcessesRunningCount=0;
       public int ProcessesRunningCount
       {
           get {return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _ProcessesRunningCount, 0, 0); }
       }

       public void StartProcessing()
       {
           if (ProcessesRunningCount < 2)
           {
               Interlocked.Increment(ref _ProcessesRunningCount);
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process());
           }
           else
           {
               //wait and start after _ProcessesRunningCount gets to less than 2
           }
       }

       private void Process()
       {
           //Do the processing
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
           Interlocked.Decrement(ref _ProcessesRunningCount);  
       }
    }
```

However I am not sure how to achieve the wait part, and not sure if that is a good way to do it, but I don't want to create a manager class that handles everything

example

```
var A = new SomeClass();
var B = new SomeClass();
var C = new SomeClass();
var D = new SomeClass();
A.StartProcessing(); //process will start
B.StartProcessing(); //process will start
C.StartProcessing(); //process will wait until _ProcessesRunningCount goes under 2
D.StartProcessing(); //process will wait until _ProcessesRunningCount goes under 2
```

Comment: Aren't you confusing the notions of process and thread? Those are quite a different artifacts. Weren't you asking about limiting the number of threads, not the number of processes?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov no i am not i start a process within a thread, i care about limiting the number of the running processes i dont care about the number of threads

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your question then.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov no prob ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a semaphore to limit the number of processes you spin up.  There's an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that should fit right into your current design.  A semaphore is similar to a mutex (lock), but it allows more than 1 thread to access the critical section.  The `Thread` in the example will start a [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and should block until the process exits.

Comment: interesting will test it out